# How to delete input field in AWK?

Tags: awk

I'm transforming some data with `awk` (or `gawk`) and want to delete one of the input fields before printing the output again.

What I want to achieve is this:

```
~ $ echo 'field1,field2,field3' | awk -F, '{transform($1); delete($2); print $0;}'
new_field1,field3
```

I can't just assign an empty string to `$2` because that leads to `new_field1,,field3` (note the two commas).

I could explicitly print only the fields that I want but that's not very elegant because I've got far more field than 3 and also there are optional fields at the end (not shown here). That's why I prefer `print $0`. Just need to get rid of some fields first.

Any idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Deleting fields in awk is notoriously difficult.  It seems to be such a simple (and often required) operation but it's harder than it should be.

See [Is there a way to completely delete fields in awk, so that extra delimiters do not print?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693608/is-there-a-way-to-completely-delete-fields-in-awk-so-that-extra-delimiters-do-n)
 from Stack Overflow for a good way to do this.

I've copied the `rmcol()` function in @ghoti's answer, so that we have a copy here on U&L:

```
function rmcol(col,     i) {
  for (i=col; i<NF; i++) {
    $i=$(i+1)
  }
  NF--
}
```

It deletes the specified column from the current input line and decrements the field counter (`NF`) to match.

I have no idea what your `transform()` function does, so I won't even attempt to duplicate that - but here's an example of using `rmcol()` in an `awk` one-liner:

```
$ echo 'field1,field2,field3' | awk -F, -v OFS=, '
  function rmcol(col,     i) {
    for (i=col; i<NF; i++) {
      $i=$(i+1)
    }
    NF--
  }

  { rmcol(2); print; }
  '
field1,field3
```

BTW, if you need to delete multiple fields from an input line, it is best/easiest to delete them in reverse order.  That is, **delete the highest-numbered fields first**.  Why?  Because the higher-numbered fields will be renumbered every time you delete a lower-numbered field, making it very difficult to keep track of which field number belongs to which field.

---

BTW, `delete()` in `awk` is for deleting elements of an array - not for deleting fields from an input line.  You could `split()` each input line (on `FS`) into an array and delete the 2nd array element, but then you'd have to write a `join()` function to print the array with a comma (or `OFS`) separating each field.

Even doing that would be more complicated than one would expect because all arrays in `awk` are associative arrays (i.e. they're **not** numerically indexed) - so `delete(array[2])` **won't** automatically shift array elements 3+ into elements 2+.  You'd have to write your own wrapper function around `delete()` to do pretty much the same thing for arrays that `rmcol()` does for input fields.

Comment: Just to say that the consequences of modifying `NF` are probably implementation-defined.

Answer (score 4):

Some alternatives

1) pre-process the input to remove the field first, easy to do with `cut` if field separator is single character

```
$ s='field1,field2,field3'
$ # use 'cut -d, -f1,3-' if --complement option is not available
$ echo "$s" | cut -d, --complement -f2
field1,field3
$ echo "$s" | cut -d, --complement -f2 | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {$1="new"} 1'
new,field3
```

2) use `perl`

```
$ # indexing starts from 0, the array @F contains the input fields
$ # $#F will give index of last element in the array
$ echo "$s" | perl -F, -lane '$F[0]="new"; print join ",", @F[0,2..$#F]'
new,field3
```

Answer (score 1):

Rewriting $0 with `gensub` may result in simpler scripts.

To remove fields 2 and 3 from a given input , you can remove the fields from $0 using `gensub` and regenerate $0 (and thus all fields) as follows:

```
> echo 'field1,field2,field3' \
    | awk -F, '{OFS=","; \
                transform($1); \
                $0=gensub(/[^,]*,/,"",2); \
                print}'
new_field1,field3
```

Note that `print` is equivalent to `print $0`.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Would you mind explaining though why you set `OFS` on every line, instead of once in the `BEGIN` section? Also, the OPs example hat comma-separated fields, so `FS=OFS=","` would seem to be the correct choice here, although since you are using `gensub()` with hard-coded delimiter anyway, you could actually completely omit the field separator specification (assumes, of course, that the OP doesn't want to peform further field-based modifications of the file).

Comment: The OFS usage is just habit and brevity.